# How we can perform different actions in single HTML form for changing url dynamically in django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

**HTML Template**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    ...
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="Next" value="Next"/>
    <input type="submit" name="Cancel" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
```

I want to navigate on different pages by click this buttons. Specifically in django environment.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more exactly what you intend these buttons to do? Would clicking 'next' save the form and clicking 'cancel' not?

Comment: Yes. I want to save data by clicking on 'next' but not when we hit 'cancel' button.

Comment: Check out my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually your form should only have one submit button. You could have cancel button in an anchor tag and that has an href to the page you want to bring them too. Something like

```
<body>
  <form>
     ...fields...
    <a href="./somewhere_else"><button type="default">Cancel</button></a>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>

  </form>
</body>
```

You could also use javascript to perform these actions.